# Move div into place on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like my header to be out of sight and then animate into place when the page loads.

At the moment I have a transition from a landing page with a fade out/in and the header should not begin to animate into place before this transition has happened. Furthermore, this transition shall only happen when I come from my landing page.

Any idea on how to do this?

Here is my fade in/out script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);

    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Comment: you should probably make the `display: none` by default and then `fadeIn`

Comment: not related to your problem, but why aren't you passing `linkLocation` to `redirectPage` instead of creating an implicit global variable?

Comment: If you are redirecting to another page where you want the animation to happen, why don’t you show us what you have tried there?

Comment: Because i really havn't got an idea off how to do it... my best guess would be something alonge the lines of this...

$(document).ready() {
            $('header').animate(
                {
            'top':'100px'
            }, 300);
             },
            );
        });

Comment: @yentup - there is debate about whether or not default display:none would get you penalized in SEO placement since it may look like hidden content to boost keywords. What he's doing here is ok, so long as it is transparent to the user. If it flickers then he should try positioning a full screen black box z-indexed over the whole content and fade that out instead of fading the body in.

Comment: @Kai Qing Good point, and what is SEO?

Comment: @yentup - Search Engine Optimization - Common buzzword that assumes all web crawlers are idiots and enables many firms to utterly rip the cash out of clients for essentially nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How bout appending a hashtag at the end of the link location? Like #dashboard or something. And then when a page is loaded you could check if the hashtag exists. If it does, then animate the body and add fade in the header in the callback of the body fade in.

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
       $('body').hide();
       //move the header to the top
       $('#header').css('top', -50);
       $('body').fadeIn(2000, function(){
           $('#header').animate({ top: '+=50', }, 2000, function() { 
              // Animation complete. 
           });
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $("body").hide();
       $("body").fadeIn(2000);
       $("a.transition").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href + '#dashboard';
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
        });
    }
});
function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
```

Comment: but i dont want the header to fade in... i want it to animate down from the top :-)

Comment: //move th header 50 px to the top and then $('#header').animate({
    top: '+=50',
    }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

Comment: I ve updated my answer with the code to animate the header and here s jsfiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/pvpGy/

Comment: i just thought that .slideDown collapses the div and then "opens" it back up again?

Comment: yea, but you can use the animate property on the 'top' attribute of the header element.

Comment: Cool - well it works just the way i want it to in your jsfiddle.. but it doesnt seem to work on my site.... :-/ 

placed this in my head - copied from your fiddle + add'ed position:relative to my css

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').css('top', -150);
    $('#header').animate({ top: '+=150', }, 2000, function() { 
        // Animation complete. 
    });
});​

Comment: is this page online? if it is then maybe i could take a look at it. You could even use http://pastebin.com/ :)

Comment: There s a bogus character at the end of your code in http://mmd3e12dae73.keaweb.dk/eksamen/js/headeranimate.js   Load this in the browser and you ll see it.. delete that bogus character and you should be good :) Apparently this is a common case when you copy paste from a jsfiddle.

Comment: you may not see the bogus character in your editor... so just make sure you have no white space after the semicolon at the end of the code

Comment: it worked on safari but not chrome so i re-wrote the code again manually.. and it worked... think the bogus character might have been picked up from copy/paste from jsfiddle.. But thanks for the help!